# Jquery from one range get one value, from other range get second value, from other range get third value etc

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

Consider this code example:

**HTML**

```
<div class="number_group">
    <span class="min">0</span> -
    <span class="max">5</span>:
    <span class="value">10</span>
</div>

<div class="number_group">
    <span class="min">6</span> -
    <span class="max">10</span>:
    <span class="value">16</span>
</div>

<div class="number_group">
    <span class="min">11</span> -
    <span class="max">15</span>;
    <span class="value">20</span>
</div>

<div class="number_group">
    <span class="min">16</span> -
    <span class="max">20</span>;
    <span class="value">22</span>
</div>

<label>
    <input type="number" id="input_val" min="0" max="20" />
    <button id="check" type="button">Check</button>
</label>
```

What i want to achive with jquery is, after user enters number in **$('input#input_val')** and clicks on **$('button#check')** function returns value in given range.

For example, if user enters number 3, function will return "10";

For example, if user enters number 8, function will return "16", etc

The list shold be dynamic, meaning **we don't know how many $('div.number_group')** are given.

Comment: How does the users input correspond to the number groups? If they enter 3 will it get a value within the range from the 3rd number group? Or will it give a number within the range of the number group with the `<span class="value">` corresponding to the user input?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Iterate over `.number_group` and find out the value based on min and max.

```js
$('#check').click(function() {
  var res,
    // get the entered value  
    num = +$('#input_val').val();
  // iterate over the divs
  $('.number_group').each(function() {
    // check the value within min and max
    if (num >= +$('.min', this).text() && num <= +$('.max', this).text()) {
      // if within range set the result as its value
      res = +$('.value', this).text();
      // break the loop by returning false, since we are findout our value
      return false;
    }
  })
  console.log(res);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="number_group">
  <span class="min">0</span> -
  <span class="max">5</span>:
  <span class="value">10</span>
</div>

<div class="number_group">
  <span class="min">6</span> -
  <span class="max">10</span>:
  <span class="value">16</span>
</div>

<div class="number_group">
  <span class="min">11</span> -
  <span class="max">15</span>;
  <span class="value">20</span>
</div>

<div class="number_group">
  <span class="min">16</span> -
  <span class="max">20</span>;
  <span class="value">22</span>
</div>

<label>
  <input type="number" id="input_val" min="0" max="20" />
  <button id="check" type="button">Check</button>
</label>
```

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative to the accepted answer, you could cache the min, max, and value in an array. This would avoid having to search the DOM on each click. On the other hand, the div.numbergroups would have to be static after page load.

```
var minMaxArr = [];

$(".number_group").each(function () {
    var minMax = {};
    $this = $(this);
    minMax['min'] = Number($this.children(".min").text());
    minMax['max'] = Number($this.children(".max").text());
    minMax['value'] = Number($this.children(".value").text());
    minMaxArr.push(minMax);
});

$("#check").on('click', function () {
    var inputVal = Number($("#input_val").val());
    var result = getValue(inputVal);
    console.log(result);
})

function getValue(inputVal) {
    for (var cnt = 0; cnt < minMaxArr.length; cnt++) {
        var minMax = minMaxArr[cnt];
        if (minMax.min <= inputVal && minMax.max >= inputVal) {
            return minMax.value;
        }
    }
    return undefined;
}
```